# Множественное (параллельное?) исполнение кода

Tags: c++, qt

Как будет исполняться функция класса которую будут вызывать обработчики сигналов QTcpSocket::readyRead, при условии что сокетов много больше одного (десятки) и сигналы от них могут приходить одновременно? Приложение однопоточное без гуя.

УПД: А если в обработчике только вычитывается полный пакет сообщения, и далее вызывается функция парсер сообщения, которая в свою очередь вызывает еще одну функцию, то для этой треьей по счету функции правило последовательности сохраняется?

Comment: Если приложение однопоточное, то сигналы от них смогут приходить только по одному.

Comment: То есть лишние будут дропаться?

Comment: Нет, отчего же. Они просто будут генерироваться по одному по мере обработки предыдущих.

Comment: А где это поведение описано?

Comment: Затрудняюсь сказать, но просто по логике для диспечеризации сигнала необходимо, чтобы поток управления перешел в диспатчер. Соответственно пока выполняется какой-то ваш код никакие сигналы не генерируются.

Comment: Они будут вызываться по-очереди, по мере генерации исходящих сообщений. Ничего дропаться не будет

Comment: @AlexanderChernin мой предыдущий вопрос все еще падает, поэтому решил проверить со всех сторон..

Comment: Я все-таки вам рекомендую изменить принцип возврата значений, то есть не через аргументы, а через RETURNS. Можно здесь задать соответствующий вопрос и народ подскажет как это реализовать. Тем самым вы избавитесь от проблемы `QVarLengthArray::append`

Comment: Из того что я нашел, функции нельзя использовать селекты и временные таблицы, а в процедуре нельзя возвращать строки.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin  А если в обработчике только вычитывается полный пакет сообщения, и далее вызывается функция парсер сообщения, которая в свою очередь вызывает еще одну функцию, то для этой треьей по счету функции правило последовательности сохраняется?

Comment: конечно сохраняется. Не понял на счет функции и селекта, почему нельзя использовать?

Comment: Не вдавался в подробности но допустим если селект то только если его результирующий набор сразу в returns

Comment: @vtt Я все же позанудствую ибо вопрос для меня принципиален: :readyRead()-->parser()-->check_ticket() и пока все функции не вернутся по стеку обратно в readyRead() он не завершиться и обработка другого входящего сообщения от другого сокета не начнется?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100854/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-dow-jhob).